# Can't convert concrete type to generic version of its Interface in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following interface:

```
public interface INotificationHandler<T>
{
    Task<T> Handle(string msg);
}
```

And several classes that happily implement it like so:

```
public class FooHandler : INotificationHandler<Foo>
{
    public Task<Foo> Handle(string msg) { return Task.FromResult<Foo>(new Foo()); }
}

public class BarHandler : INotificationHandler<Bar>
{
    public Task<Bar> Handle(string msg) { return Task.FromResult<Bar>(new Bar()); }
}
```

I'd like to keep a collection of INotificationHandler instances in a collection and when I get a message "foo", use the FooHandler, "bar" gets the BarHandler, etc...

```
var notificationHandlers = new Dictionary<string, INotificationHandler<object>>();
notificationHandlers["foo"] = new FooHandler();
notificationHandlers["bar"] = new BarHandler();
...
public void MessageReceived(string type, string msg)
{
    INotificationHandler<object> handler = notificationHandlers[type];
    handler.Notify(msg).ContinueWith((result) => /* do stuff with a plain object */)
}
```

However this fails to compile because my generic has no common base type, which is by design. Any object should be able to be returned from a INotificationHandler in `MessageReceived`.

> Cannot implicitly convert type `FooHandler` to `INotificationHandler<object>`. 
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I work with `INotificationHandler<T>` so that I don't need care about the generic types of its concrete implementations?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `public interface INotificationHandler<out T>` ?

Comment: In my opinion this completely defeats the purpose of generics.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel I did try that, however T must be invariantly valid?
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'INotificationHandler<T>.Handle(string)'. 'T' is covariant.

Comment: I don't think you can make this interface covariant in `T` since `Task<T>` is invariant. Create a wrapper class which implements `INotificationHandler<object>` and use that.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing that `Task<T>` is invariant in `T`, which is a shame.

Comment: @juharr Other places in the codebase benefit from INotificationHandler being a generic, however there are some situations where I don't care about the generic type it returns, just that it returns some object. In this case its for serialization.

Comment: Agree to @juharr, for your code just make `INotificationHandler ` non-generic will work.

Comment: It's impossible, the sample seems like a bad app design.

Comment: What is a goal you try to achieve?

Comment: What you plan to do here? "ContinueWith((result) => /* do stuff with a plain object */)"

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh Without going in to too much detail, the message comes in from a WebView, is processed by an INotificationHandler and then the result serialized and forwarded back to JavaScript inside the WebView. 

The specific INotificationHandler implementations do care about types, but the code that forwards the serialized objects back to JavaScript does not.

Comment: Maybe look at what open-source IoC containers do; they have to deal with the same problem of  "I need to temporarily forget type information to keep a collection of these heterogeneous objects but then return them with the right type later".

Comment: The problem is that `Task<T>` is a class and not an interface. You could do this by creating an `ITask<out T>` interface, a class that implements it and wraps a `Task<T>`, and a method (like an extension method on `Task<T>`) that takes a `Task<T>` and returns an `ITask<T>`. However this is not trivial to do. A google search for *covariant task interface* gave me [this](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: If the goal is the serialized object you can use Task<object> and avoid a generic interface.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh That is what I was doing before, however I lost type safety within my INotificationHandlers. I accidentally returned the wrong type, caused a bug, and upon discovery decided maybe it'd be best to avoid Task<object> if possible.

Comment: @svinja That looks like it would work, but wow thats a lot of code to solve this localized little problem! I may switch back to Task<object> before dragging in all that code.

Comment: @svinja awesome find!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a type safety you can use the following hierarchy.

```
public interface INotificationHandler
{
    Task<object> Handle(string msg);
}

public abstract BaseHandler<T> : INotificationHandler
{
    Task<object> INotificationHandler.Handle(string msg)
    {
        return Handle(msg);
    }

    public abstract Task<T> Handle(string msg);
}

public class FooHandler : BaseHandler<Foo>
{
    public override Task<Foo> Handle(string msg) { return Task.FromResult<Foo>(new Foo()); }
}

public class BarHandler : BaseHandler<Bar>
{
    public override Task<Bar> Handle(string msg) { return Task.FromResult<Bar>(new Bar()); }
}

var notificationHandlers = new Dictionary<string, INotificationHandler>();
notificationHandlers["foo"] = new FooHandler();
notificationHandlers["bar"] = new BarHandler();
...
public void MessageReceived(string type, string msg)
{
    INotificationHandler handler = notificationHandlers[type];
    handler.Notify(msg).ContinueWith((result) => /* do stuff with a plain object */)
}
```

Comment: This will not work if FooHandler and BarHandler cant inherit from same BaseHandler. As we know object can inherit only from one class.

Comment: The both of them are inherited from the same BaseHandler

Comment: Yes it's true in your case. Imagine that you already have class FooHandler that inherits from A and BarHandler that inherits from B (lets say A is Windows Control and B is Web Control). In this case your architecture can't work because FooHandler and BarHandler will not be allowed to inherit from BaseHandler. This is what I wanted to point out.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in the case of this issue it's a good solution.